# How to replace #include <optional>

Tags: c++, c++14

I come to you today with another question that my brain can't process by itself:
I got a cpp file that includes optional as a header file. Unfortunately, this works only on c++17 forwards, and I'm trying to compile it in c++14. This cpp file uses optional like this

```
std::optional<std::string> GetStringPropertyValueFromJson(const std::string& Property, const web::json::value& Json)
{
    if (Json.has_field(utility::conversions::to_string_t(Property)))
    {
        auto& propertyValue = Json.at(utility::conversions::to_string_t(Property));
        if (propertyValue.is_string())
        {
            return std::optional<std::string>{utility::conversions::to_utf8string(propertyValue.as_string())};
        }
    }

    return std::nullopt;
}
```

and then the function is used to assign values like this:

```
std::string tokenType = GetStringPropertyValueFromJson("token_type", responseContent).value_or("");
std::string accessToken = GetStringPropertyValueFromJson("access_token", responseContent).value_or("");
```

Please help me with a proper substitution for OPTIONAL. Thanks and much love

PS: From what i've read, you can replace optional with pair somehow in order to get a similar result, but I don't really know how exactly.

PPS: I am new here so any tips on how to better write my questions or anything else are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you have boost installed, `boost::optional` should be a reasonable substitute.

Comment: `optional` can be implemented in C++14, so either use a library as `boost` which provide its own, or reimplement it.

Comment: I compile to C++14 and use boost::optional (in win32, win64, and rhel). I have a project to move to C++17, whereupon I believe the migration to std::optional is simple.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in C++14 the `optional` header could be included by `#include <experimental/optional>`.

Comment: hello @jakub, thanks for the reply, tried your version and I somehow got more errors than before. Will look into it more.

Comment: @icsjrm it could be because a lot might have changed in this header when it has been moved from ```std::experimental``` to ```std```.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method signature to

```
std::string GetStringPropertyValueFromJson(const std::string& Property, const web::json::value& Json)
```

and in the end just return the empty string

```
return "";
```

Then later in your code use it without `std::optional::value_or`:

```
std::string tokenType = GetStringPropertyValueFromJson("token_type", responseContent);
```

The logic is exactly the same and you don't use `std::optional`.

I see now your other question about possibility to use `std::pair`. Yes, you could also change your method to:

```
std::pair<std::string, bool> GetStringPropertyValueFromJson(const std::string& Property, const web::json::value& Json)
```

and return `std::make_pair(valueFromJson, true)` in case your json property has been found, or `std::make_pair("", false)` in case it was not. This also solves the problem with empty (but existing) json property.

Comment: how do you distinguish the case when the fields value is `""` ?

Comment: well, actually OPs code does not make this distinction as anyhow eventually they call `value_or("")`

Comment: What if it's not `std::string`, but some non-default-constructible - or even worse, something where ctor interacts with environment, therefore you cannot simply construct it?

Comment: @pptaszni, should i change anything in the part where i use the function or will it stay the same? eg: GetStringPropertyValueFromJson("token_type", responseContent)

Comment: @lorro then I would suggest different solution. Having seen the code in question, I think that first part of my answer is sufficient, because I'm quite sure that OP just needs to do some easy refactor to be able to compile the project without c++17 support. I know that the answer is not generic.

Comment: @icsjrm if the first part of the answer is sufficient for you, then just use `std::string tokenType = GetStringPropertyValueFromJson("token_type", responseContent);`. If you want to use `std::pair`, then `auto result = GetStringPropertyValueFromJson("token_type", responseContent)` and you need to check if it was successful `if (result.second) { tokenType = result.first; }`

Answer (score 1):

A poor mans optional string that should be sufficient for your code is this:

```
struct my_nullopt {};


struct my_optional {
private:
     std::string value; 
     bool has_value = false;
public:
     my_optional(my_nullopt) {} 
     my_optional(const std::string& v) : value(v),has_value(true) {}
     T value_or(const std::string& v) { 
        return has_value ? value : v;
     }
};
```

Its a rather limited interface, for example it is not possible to set the value after construction. But it appears that you do not need that.

Alternatively you can use `boost/optional`.

Note that the tip you got about using a `pair` is just what I did above: The value and a `bool`. Just that `std::pair` is for cases where you cannot give better names than `first` and `second` (eg in generic code), but it is simple to provide a better interface than `std::pair` does here. With a pair the `value_or` would be something along the line of `x.first ? x.second : ""`.

---

PS: Only in the end I realized that the code you present does not actually make use of what `std::optional` has to offer. As you are calling `value_or("")`, you cannot distinguish between a field with value `""` or `""` because the optional had no value. Because of that, the most simple solution is to use a plain `std::string` and return `""` instead of `std::nullopt`.

Comment: DON'T do this. This constructs `T` regardless of if you want it or not. If it's a resource, it'll always use it - e.g., it'll always open a file.

Comment: @lorro you are right. changed it to be `std::string`.

Comment: [`nullopt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t) has also some constraint (no default constructible), but as you said, *"poor mans optional"*.

Comment: @Jarod42 only after writing the answer I realized that OP does not need any optional as they either use the actual string or `""`, ie they do not need a `nullopt` / the empty state. I decided to leave the answer up anyhow, maybe it will be useful to anybody